# RESTKit POST Request Tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I would like to know if there is a specific tutorial on how to do a POST request with RESTKit. I have looked at some tutorials but I haven't found any that say, "This is exactly how you do a POST request with RESTKit." Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you already have a mapped model, you can simply perform this:

First, set a `requestDescriptor` with the inverseMapping of your `responseDescriptor`, assuming you have one with your mapping.

```
//This is used for mapping responses, you already should have one of this. PS:[Data mapping] is a method that returns an RKObjectMapping for my model. You should create yours or use a previous created one
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[Data mapping] pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"data" statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
[[RKObjectManager sharedInstance] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

//Inverse mapping, to perform a POST
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[[Data mapping] inverseMapping]  objectClass:[Data class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedInstance] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

After that, to perform a POST, just simply call the method below. Restkit will get the instance that you are trying to post, serialize it and send to the path chosen.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedInstance] postObject:instanceOfYourModel path:yourPathHere parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}];
```

If you don't have a mapped model, let me know so we can try something else.

Comment: I don't really know what a mapped model is. Is it this: RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Login class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"username", @"password"]];
    return mapping;

Comment: Yes. Your object mapping has a method [mapping inverseMapping]. Just create a request descriptor, like I shown, andd it to your RKObject Manager, and you will be able to perform a postObject. Any doubts, please ask

Comment: Lucas, I wish I could accept the answer: it helped me a lot. +1 it.

Comment: The value of "parameters" argument must be passed with a dictionary object to avoid request.body = null  in method  [[RKObjectManager sharedInstance] postObject:instanceOfYourModel path:yourPathHere    parameters:nil success:....   That is not only for the POST method but the GET as well.

Comment: At least when I last tested Restkit (version 0.20.0), the `postObject:` method automatically serializes the object passed in the parameter, using the `RKRequestDescriptor`, and send to server in the body of the request, without the need of passing any `parameters`, like you would have to if was using `AFNetwork`, for example.

Comment: I don't have mapping , could you please provide me this methodology ?

Comment: Hello @wod, above you can see, in Restkit documentation, how to create a mapping for your model, using the class `RKObjectMapping`. This instance of `RKObjectMapping` is the mapping object that will be used in the code of this answer. 
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Comment: I need to used postObject without entity mapping

Comment: Well, unfortunately that's not possible. If you really don't want to use a entity mapping, you can use `postPath:parameters:success:failure:` method of your `[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient`. See the documentation of this method for more information: 

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/postPath:parameters:success:failure:

Comment: When i used this methodology i get null body ,could you help me please?

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell the problem without more informations. You can open a question with details and post the link here, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Hi @Lucas Eduardo    I am not able to post on this url, i am getting 500 error and "Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Root element is missing." error message on below link. please help me
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

Comment: My working code is :- (void)postOnServer{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
    RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
    [venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"Celsius"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping pathPattern:@"/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit"

Comment: keyPath:@"string" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[venueMapping inverseMapping]  objectClass:[Venue class] rootKeyPath:nil];

Comment: success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
        
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }];
}

Comment: @kulss, could you please create a new question? Post the link here that I'll sure take a look. It's kinda difficult to look your code in this way.